# How do you get the highest value of each individual string name in an array of strings that contain a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would you go about getting the highest number of each color in the following array?

```
var array = ["Black 1", "Black 4", "Green 2", "Green 8", "Green 6", "Green 3", "Yellow 2"]
```

The result array should be:

```
["Black 4", "Green 8", "Yellow 2"]
```

Any tips or guidance would be extremely appreciated.
I was thinking that each value would need to be split between the color and the number but it's not clicking to me how to follow through with that.

Comment: Please share your efforts so far as a [mcve].

Comment: Don't just provide a specification and expect code as a result.  What [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) have you done? What have you tried to date?

Comment: `split()` by spaces, then `parseInt` index one. Arrange the ints, and join the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through your array using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). As you mentioned, you can use `.split()` to separate the colour from the number. Once you have both components, you can destructure the array you get from splitting your string to obtain the `colour` and the number (`score`) into separate variables. Using `.reduce()`, you can map to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which stores keys as being the colours, and values as being the max score. In order to get the max score, you can check if the Map already has a number for your colour (indicating it has already been seen), and if it does, grab the max between the current number (`score`) and the current number stored in the Map, otherwise, you can make the Map store the current number `score` by taking the max between `-Infinity` and the current score value:

```js
const array = ["Black 1", "Black 4", "Green 2", "Green 8", "Green 6", "Green 3", "Yellow 2"];

const res = Array.from(array.reduce((map, str) => {
  const [color, score] = str.split(" ");
  const maxScore = Math.max(map.get(color) ?? -Infinity, score);
  return map.set(color, maxScore);
}, new Map), entry => entry.join(" "));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

here's my take:

```
var array = ["Black 1", "Black 4", "Green 2", "Green 8", "Green 6", "Green 3", "Yellow 2"];
const temp = {};
array.forEach(color => {
  const [name, value] = color.split(' ');
  temp[name] = Math.max(value, temp[name] || 0);
});
const result = Object.entries(temp).map(color => `${color[0]} ${color[1]}`);
```

Like you said, I split each string into its name and value. Then keep track of the maximums in an object (called temp here). And finally convert to an array.

Comment: well, this is not so accurate since you have used `Math.max(value, temp[name] || 0)` and it will not give the exact result if there is input `"Black -1"`

Comment: Also would fail if the color name has a space in it. There is not enough context in the question to know, so I think it is ok to assume the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

A simple reduce would do the trick.

Like this (I am using a nested IIFE in this implementation.):

```js
 

var array = ["Black 1", "Black 4", "Green 2", "Green 8", "Green 6", "Green 3", "Yellow 2"]

var result = array.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => 
      (([k, v]) => ({...acc, [k]: Math.max(v, acc[k] || 0)})
      )(cur.match(/(.*)(\d+)/).slice(1)), // IIFE call
      {})

console.log(Object.entries(result).map(([k, v]) => `${k}${v}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string and then using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the largest number and then finally using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the final result.

```js
var array = [
  "Black 1",
  "Black 4",
  "Green 2",
  "Green 8",
  "Green 6",
  "Green 3",
  "Yellow 2",
];

const mapObj = new Map();

array
  .map((s) => s.split(" "))
  .forEach(([k, v]) =>
    mapObj.set(k, Math.max(mapObj.get(k) ?? Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, v))
  );

const result = [...mapObj].map(([k, v]) => `${k} ${v}`);
console.log(result);
```